# javascript file upload using POST Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to record a video and upload to server. I am able create video but the upload is not working. What could i be doing wrong. i tried downloading the file directly from server(a.click()). it works but i am not able to upload to nodejs server

i am able to post text values and fetch from server                                 i am able to upload files chosen from file system using a form in html and pass a file chosen as it directly  ..below

```
<form id="uploadForm"
      enctype="multipart/form-data"
      action="/upload"
      method="post">
  <input type="file" name="file" />
  <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
  <span id = "status"></span>
</form>
```

i am also able send files with socket.io if is do socket.emit('msg',files)  But i cannot use socket  on prod environment. I am open to any other way to send recorded file to nodejs server

Server Code

```js
var express = require("express");
var multer = require('multer');

var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, './uploads');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
              var datetimestamp = Date.now();
              cb(null, file.originalname + '-' + datetimestamp + '.' + file.originalname.split('.')[file.originalname.split('.').length -1])
          }
    });
var upload = multer({ storage : storage}).single('file');
app.get('/',function(req,res){
      res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});
app.post('/uploadlocal',function(req,res){

 upload(req,res,function(err) {console.log(req.files);
 console.log(req.body);

  if(err) {
   return res.end("Error uploading file.");
  }
 
  res.end("File is uploaded");
 });
});



app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("Working on port 3000");
});
```

Client Code

```js
function download() {
  var blob = new Blob(recordedBlobs, {type: 'video/webm'});
  var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      var files = {

                                  video: {
                                      type: 'video/webm',
                                      dataURL: url
                                  }
                            };
  console.log('recording done');

  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.style.display = 'none';
  a.href = url;
  a.download = 'test.webm';
  document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
  postclick(files);

  setTimeout(function() {
    document.body.removeChild(a);
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  }, 100);
}


function postclick(data) {
    var form = $('<form></form>');

    form.attr("method", "post");
    form.attr("action", '/uploadlocal');
    var field = $('<input></input>');
    field.attr("type", "text");
 field.attr("name", 'file');
    field.attr("value", data );

        form.append(field);
    $(document.body).append(form);
    form.submit();
}
```

Comment: Can you confirm whether the folder where you try to upload your files => `./uploads` has all the required read/write permissions set?

Comment: permissions are fine

Comment: Two things, Do you have the `enctype` set properly in your `<form>` tag?, also did you set the `accept` attribute in your `<input type="file"..` tag as `accept="video/mp4,video/x-m4v,video/*"` ?

Comment: Update your mime type accordingly in your `accept` attribute, I have given `mp4` and `x-m4u` just for reference

Comment: Could you share and example..I am able to upload media directly from HTML directly

Comment: Have you tried adding the `accept` attribute to this line `<input type="file" name="file" />` in your code (according to the mime type of the video that you are trying to upload?

Comment: It dint work...I am building the form in javascript ...I added mime type on postclick function  - > field.attr("name", 'file');
 field.attr("accept",'video/*');
    field.attr("value", data );

Answer (score 0):

resolved the issue by creating xmlhttprequest

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', blob, "test.webm");
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST", "/upload");
request.send(formData);
```